# MySQL Query for getting payments evolution graph during latest 12 months

Tags: mysql, sql

My app stores payments done by clients. At the end of every month, the total paid that month is calculated and given to owner: I have a payments table that has the following fields (the most important).

**id, datepaid, endingdate (actual month's closing date), ammount, type, code, ...**

Now, having a year of payments, I've been asked to create a graph of payments evolution (totals) of latest 12 months.

By reading, etc. this is the query I've got, **but I don't know how to get the latest 12 months totals (and to get 0 in case no payment was done that month)....**

```
    SELECT id, endingdate, datepaid, SUM(ammount) AS total
    FROM `sis_payments` 
    WHERE endingdate >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
    GROUP BY endingdate
```

I know it may be badly designed, but it's what I was given... any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `GROUP BY YEAR(endingdate), MONTH(endingdate)`, or something equivalent using `DATE_FORMAT`. Take a look at the [Mysql documentation for DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Also, don't include the date fields (`endingdate`, `datepaid`) in the `SELECT` clause. Instead, use `YEAR(endingdate), MONTH(endingdate)`, just like in `GROUP BY`.

Getting 0 when there were no payments that month is a little more complicated in SQL. You could handle that in PHP, after running the query.

**UPDATE**

Example using DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(mrendido,'%y-%m') as xyearmonth, 
    SUM(FORMAT(ammountpaid,2)) AS ammtotal 
FROM sis_pyments
WHERE mrendido >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
GROUP BY xyearmonth 
ORDER BY xyearmonth ASC
```

Comment: Solved with this query: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mrendido,'%m') as xmonth, DATE_FORMAT(mrendido,'%y') as xyear, SUM(FORMAT(ammountpaid,2)) AS ammtotal
 FROM sis_pyments WHERE mrendido >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
 GROUP BY xmonth, xyear
 ORDER BY xyear, xmonth ASC

Comment: Unless you need to display month and year separately, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to make your query more concise. I'm updating my original answer with an example.

Comment: wow, didn't notice that. concatening month+year with date_format and grouping by this generated field made all easier. thanks!